# Why is it an interior minimum

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I just solved the following exercise:

(Here $I=(a,b)$ is an open interval, possibly $a,b=\pm \infty$ and $\alpha : I \to \mathbb R^3$ is smooth.)

Let $\alpha$ be a parametrized curve that does not pass through $(0,0,0)$. If $\alpha (t_0)$ is the point at which the trace of $\alpha$ is closest to the origin and $\alpha'(t_0)\neq 0$ show that the position vector $\alpha (t_0)$ is orthogonal to $\alpha'(t_0)$.

Here's how I did it: The goal is to show that $\alpha' \cdot \alpha (t_0) =0$. Note that $|\alpha(t)|$ is the distance of the trace at $t$ from the origin. Then its derivative at $t_0$ must be zero. From computing this derivative it readily follows that $\alpha' \cdot \alpha (t_0) =0$.

The problem I have with my solution is the assumption that ${d \over dt}|\alpha(t_0)|=0$. Concretely, why is it not possible that this distance gets smaller the closer $t$ gets to one of the endpoints $a$ or $b$? For example this would be the case if the distance was represented by a line. But for some reason this is not possible.

Comment: Yes, this could theoretically be possible, but in the exercise it was given that the distance is minimal in $t_0$. It doesn't matter actually, since you only need a local minimum.